# En un array[] tengo que sacar el maximo y si otra posicion tambien es maximo concatenarlo

Tags: java, array

1.- En un campeonato participan los siguientes países: “España”, “Francia” “Reino Unido”, “Italia”, “Alemania” y “Dinamarca”. Cada país obtiene una puntuación (entera entre 1 y 10 que se genera de forma aleatoria). Se pide calcular los países que han obtenido el primer y segundo premio. (Puede haber varios países con la misma puntuación). Se pide resolver el problema usando  arrays.

Ejemplo: suponiendo que el orden de los países es el anterior y que las puntuaciones son  respectivamente 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 3 la salida sería:
Ganador del primer premio: Francia
Segundo premio: España

```
package arrays;

public class Paises {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] listaPaises= {"España", "Francia", "Reino Unido", "Italia", "Alemania","Dinamarca"};
        int max =Integer.MIN_VALUE,posPai = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < listaPaises.length; i++) {
            int puntuaciones = (int)(Math.random()*9+1);
            System.out.print(puntuaciones+" ");
            if (puntuaciones>max) {
                max=puntuaciones;
                 posPai = i;
                 listaPaises[posPai]+=" "+listaPaises[i];
            }
            //listaPaises[i]
        } 
        System.out.println(" "+max);
        System.out.println("El ganador es "+listaPaises[posPai]);
    }

}
```

Lo he intentado de varias formas pero no doy con la clave.

Comment: ¿Qué problema te da tu código? ¿En qué parte?

Comment: El problema es que si hay dos numeros maximos que corresponden a diferentes paises no me los saca, solo consigo que me saque el mismo repetido

Comment: intenta cambiar el simbolo a `>=`

Comment: Eso lo tambien lo probe pero igual me sale repetido el primero que coge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es chequear si las dos puntuaciones son iguales y si lo son concatenar, algo asi:

```
package arrays;

public class Paises {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] listaPaises= {"España", "Francia", "Reino Unido", "Italia", "Alemania","Dinamarca"};
        int max =Integer.MIN_VALUE,posPai = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < listaPaises.length; i++) {
            int puntuaciones = (int)(Math.random()*9+1);
            System.out.print(puntuaciones+" ");
            if (puntuaciones>max) {
                max=puntuaciones;
                 posPai = i;
                 listaPaises[posPai]=listaPaises[i];
            } else if (puntuaciones == max) {
                 listaPaises[posPai]+=" "+listaPaises[i]; 
            }
            //listaPaises[i]
        } 
        System.out.println(" "+max);
        System.out.println("El ganador es "+listaPaises[posPai]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Al ejecutar tu codigo me sale bien pero juraria haber echo eso!! .         
 de todas formas creia que no era del todo correcto cerrar con un else if

Comment: Que yo sepa else if no tiene nada de malo

Comment: Me parecia raro , pues que rabia juraria haber echo eso.. Muchas gracias

Comment: No se enoje, lo importante es que ya salio

Answer (score 1):

Para mostrar el primer y segundo equipo con más puntos necesitas dos variables distintas para guardar por separado el primero y el segundo a medida que recorres el for. Similar a tu código pero con dos max y dos posPai. Así:

```
public class Paises {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] listaPaises = { "España", "Francia", "Reino Unido", "Italia", "Alemania", "Dinamarca" };
        int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int posPai1 = -1;
        int posPai2 = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < listaPaises.length; i++) {
            int puntuaciones = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);
            System.out.print(puntuaciones + " ");

            // Si es mayor o = que el 1º (y por lo tanto también mayor que el 2º)
            // Pasamos el 1º al 2º y actualizamos el nuevo 1º
            if (puntuaciones >= max1) {
                max2 = max1;
                max1 = puntuaciones;
                posPai2 = posPai1;
                posPai1 = i;
            }
            // Si es mayor o igual que el 2º (pero no mayor o = que el 1º)
            // Actualizamos el nuevo 2º
            else if (puntuaciones >= max2) {
                max2 = puntuaciones;
                posPai2 = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(" Max: " + max1 + " " + max2);
        System.out.println("Ganador del primer premio: " + listaPaises[posPai1] + " Segundo premio: " + listaPaises[posPai2] );
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
El enunciado dice que pueden haber varios países con la misma puntuación, pero no deja claro qué hay que hacer en tal caso. Por ejemplo si tenemos 9 9 8 8 7 7 ¿Los dos 9 serían primer y segundo puesto aleatoriamente? ¿O tendríamos dos primeros puestos con 9 y dos segundos puestos con 8? ¿Y si hay tres con el mismo número?

Lo más sencillo sería que pudieran haber varios equipos con el mismo puesto, pero el enunciado no lo deja claro.

Comment: Todos los primeros y  todos segundos, pero es verdad no queda muy claro.